# How do I partially prefill a query box?

Tags: html

I have used this code to show a Google web search box

```
<form method="get" action="https://google.com/search">
    <input type="text" name="q"  size="31" value=" ">
</form>
```

I would like to have the box prefilled with the text
"What to do in" and let the user type the location ( example type only Sydney )
so the  query will be:
 What to do in Sydney"
 Is it possible?
 I'm just a beginner and do not know much about HTML. 
 Your help would be very appreciated.
 Thank you
Fernando

Comment: Try searching for previous questions of same type before posting a question , approx 70% cases are a direct hit and you will get your solution

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue with the above answers is that the user can just delete the whole text and start again..

so if you really want to limit it to "what to do in ..." then you should only offer up the text input for the location.. similar to what raam86's answer was.

```
<form method="get" action="https://google.com/search">
    <label for="whattodo">What to do in</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="q" id="real_input" value="what to do in" />
    <input type="text" id="whattodo" onkeyup="fillForm(this.value);" />
</form>

<script>
function fillForm( _val )
{
    document.getElementById('real_input').value = 'what to do in ' + _val;
}
</script>
```

Use `label` where possible - this relates the text to the `input` area - which means, if a user clicks on the `label` they'll be focused into the input box ready to type..

You'll notice that there's a hidden input and also a text input

the hidden input gets filled with "what to do in " as well as the text from the text field (as the user types, a bit of javascript is triggered called `fillForm()` which appends the hidden field (the query field) with the user inputted text.. this ensures that it's always going to have "what to do in" prepended to the query.

You should place

```
function fillForm( _val )
{
    document.getElementById('real_input').value = 'what to do in ' + _val;
}
```

between the `<head>` and `</head>` of your HTML document.

Comment: Thank you.Works perfectly. I'm worried that once google will be closed in about a week the search is not going to work anymore. How could I change the search to yahoo.com

Comment: google be closed? Let's hope not!.. but just change the `action="https://google.com/search"` to `action="http://uk.search.yahoo.com/search?p="` - please accept my answer if you're happy with it by clicking the big tick at the top of this answer :-)

Comment: Why should I add the function fillForm value between the <head> and </head>.

Comment: It's good practice to add javascript into the `<head></head>` of your document

Comment: @DannyHearnah It's not good practice to put JS in the head. The opposite is true actually.Another bad practice is binding events to the element and using `addEventListener`

Answer (score 0):

use `value = "What to do in"` and this will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in HTML only, then do like this:

```
<input type="text" name="q"  size="31" value="What to do in ">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should build it in a way it is clear to the user his search will be appened to this line: 
What to do in: 
something like

```
<span>What to do in</span><input type="text" id="search" name="q"  size="31" value=" ">
```

and in js or anything else:

```
$.get('https://www.google.co.il/search?q=what to do in ' + $('#search').val(),function(data){
    //Do stuff with seach results 
})
```

You can then append the word to the query

Comment: This is even better!!